# Best approach to testing methods run from initialize with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following code (Chess implementation, I'm going through theodinproject.com path):

```
class Move
 def initialize(player, board)
  @player     = player
  @board      = board
  @from       = ask_for_move_details("from")
  @from_sq    = @board[@from.to_sym]
  @from_piece = @from_sq[:piece]
  @to         = ask_for_move_details("to")
  @to_sq      = @board[@to.to_sym]
  make_a_move if move_allowed?
 end

 def ask_for_move_details(from_or_to)
   begin
     msg_ask_for_move_details(@player, from_or_to)
     chosen_address = gets.chomp.to_s
     raise unless address_valid?(chosen_address)
   rescue
     msg_move_not_allowed
     retry
   end
   chosen_address
 end
 ...
end
```

I need to test `ask_for_move_details("from"/"to")` methods which are run  when object instance is being created.

The goal is to e.g. make `@from` variable get a value of `"a1"` and `@to` variable to get `"a6"` value. So far I have came up only with this:

```
allow(Move).to receive(:gets).and_return("a1", "a6")
```

but it doesn't work, as `@from` gets the nil value and the test fails.

I know that initialize method should not be tested at all, but the situation makes it impossible to create an instance of the object and therefore test its methods. Should I just refactor the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ask_for_move_details("from"/"to")` can be stubbed using `allow_any_instance_of` with `with`.

For example:

```
class A
  def a(b)
  end
end

describe do
  before do
    allow_any_instance_of(A).to receive(:a).with(1) { 2 }
    allow_any_instance_of(A).to receive(:a).with(2) { 3 }
  end

  it do
    expect(A.new.a(1)).to eq 2
    expect(A.new.a(2)).to eq 3
  end
end
```

So, the value returned by `ask_for_move_details` can be stubbed depending on the argument passed to this method:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Move).to receive(:ask_for_move_details).with("from") { "a1" }
allow_any_instance_of(Move).to receive(:ask_for_move_details).with("to") { "a6" }
```